# Java - Removing element from a Linked List using iterator

Tags: java, linked-list, iterator, listiterator

I have a program that reads in entries that are added to a linked list, and the method below which deletes entries. Currently, the method seems to go through the list and, once it finds the chosen entry, deletes it *as well as all of the entries before it*, instead of just the individual entry. Removing the break; makes the method just remove all entries in the list.

```
LinkedList<Entry> entryList = new LinkedList<Entry>();
ListIterator<Entry> entryIterator = entryList.listIterator();

public void deleteEntry(int number) {
    while(entryIterator.hasNext()) {
        Entry entry = entryIterator.next();
        if((entry.getNumber() == number)) {
                entryIterator.remove();
                //break;
        }
    }
}
```

I have a feeling that the problem is elsewhere but can't figure it out - i'm pretty new to java. Thanks!

Comment: Looks just fine to me

Comment: The problem is probably elsewhere. Is `number` possibly a static member of `Entry`?

Comment: I don't think the extra entries are getting removed at all.  I think you're fooling yourself into thinking that they are, by examining the iterator instead of examining the original list.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like

```
entry.getNumber() == number
```

is always TRUE, so problem is not in this code but somewhere else.

Maybe Entry number defined as static or all elements in the list are the same object.

Comment: I've managed to get the method to behave correctly. I noticed that I had a while loop at the end of another similar method to reset the iterator that worked fine.I added it to the deleteEntry method and it now works. I've never used linked lists before so I'm not sure how it's fixed or how efficient it is, but it works at last.

    public void deleteEntry(int number) {
  while(entryIterator.hasNext()) {
   Entry entry = entryIterator.next();
   if((entry.getNumber() == number)) {
    entryIterator.remove();   
   }
  }
  while(entryIterator.hasPrevious()) {
   entryIterator.previous();
  }
 }

Comment: @user3553826 - please read [this](http://pragprog.com/the-pragmatic-programmer/extracts/coincidence), then reread the documentation for [ListIterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html). What you're doing is quite simply **wrong**, and isn't solving whatever real problem you might be having.

Comment: @kdgregory - Of course as soon as posting that comment I tested to find out why it solved the problem. I wouldn't be foolish enough to find a solution by coincidence and go about learning what the problem was and how it was solved. I hadn't studied the API in detail and I realised what the error was, turns out I thought I was creating a new iterator each time, when in reality I was reusing the same one. It meant that the iterator had to be reset to the start of the list before any operations could be done.